# Set a defined stdout output area for Windows batch output?

Tags: windows, batch-file, stdout

I have a Windows batch which does some things.  (Quite long, VM tasks, with QEMU and Lua).

I would like to pipe all stdout coming from the batch's echo and call commands (stdout) to a defined section of the Windows Consule display window, for drawing a shaded grey title bar on the top and bottom of the window while output displays what the script is doing.

Sort of like a text area, that auto-wraps and will scroll as the CMD window does, in a defined section of the window (retro example, the DOOM wad loader, that puts red title bars on the top and bottom during initialization, but here I'd like it with the lesser-annoying color choice).

I'm wondering if this can be done, reasonably, in either batch or an executable wrapper that the batch file can be piped to, where it will send its stdout?

---

EDIT:  **Update 1**

**Suggestion: PowerShell?**

Embedding PowerShell to accomplish the setup of the console window is all fine and dandy, but keep in mind that most fair people set PowerShell execution permissions to Restricted.  Meaning adding auto-elevation VBScript and a PowerShell permission adjuster/auto-unblocker/Restricted permission restoration would add unnecessary bulk, and an annoying UAC prompt to my script.

This suggestion also runs the risk of tripping a smart AV into a false positive over the polyglot expansion features of such a script.

**Suggestion: ANSI Escape Characters**

Very good tricky for efficient batch, I would say.  I'm aware of the inverted grey, which would display the title bars adiquitely.  Now the answer has been pointed in the right direction.  Are there ANSI Escape Sequences to adjust the output buffer?  This suggestion isn't explicitly locked to Windows 10 if you adjust the Consule Window's codepage.

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This sort of thing is _extremely_ annoying to do in batch. It's technically possible, but I highly recommend against doing it.

Comment: Considering this particular script runs for an extended length of time and needs to display graphical status to the user, I thought it operable to do so.

This is a remote control VM scripting batch.  I'd like to have the user have something to look at, especially during an operation such as defragmenting, and zeroing free space, to prepare for resizing.  We aren't talking rainbow effects, just a simple grey upper/lower bar announcing its extended presence.

Comment: I would recommend power shell, are you allowed to use PS, or it has to be specifically batch?

Comment: If you're using win10, you can use ansi escape sequences

Comment: @QueenSvetlana powershell is fine, though the script is going to be distributed, so I'd need to include an auto-elevating permission adjuster which unblocks itself.  (most people are smart enough to set Powershell's permissions to Restricted, so script enabling is a chore)  Its fairly easy to embed the Powershell code and VBScript auto-elevation with Powershell permission adjust for remote machines.  A smart AV would throw a false positive at implementations like those.

Comment: @jeb I'm aware of ANSI escape sequences for inverted grey.  The question is, which ones adjust the display column of the output buffer, if ANSI is to be applicably used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small sample with ansi escape sequences.
It splits the screen into two seperate regions,
the first 10 lines are fixed without scrolling, the below region uses scrolling.

```
@echo off
call :cls
call :setWindowSize 50 120
call :setWindowPos 1040 0
call :splitWindow 11
call :gotoxy 1 1
for /L %%n in (1 1 5) do (
    echo Job: %%n
)
call :gotoxy 1 20
for /L %%n in (1 1 50) do (
    echo Cnt: %%n
)
exit /b

:setWindowSize
set "lines=%1
set "columns=%2"
call :echo-e "\e[8;%lines%;%columns%t";

:gotoxy
set "y=%1"
set "x=%2"
call :echo-e "\e[%x%;%y%H"
exit /b

:cls
call :echo-e "\e[2J"
exit /b

:setWindowPos
set "x=%1"
set "y=%2"
call :echo-e "\e[3;%x%;%y%t";
exit /b

:splitWindow
set /a "pos=%1 - 1"
call :echo-e "\ec\e[2J\e[%1;80r\e[%pos%H\e[46m\e[K\e[0m"
exit /b

:windowToFront
call :echo-e "\e[2t""\e[1t"
exit /b

:echo-e
set "arg1=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "arg1=!arg1:\x=0x!"
set "arg1=!arg1:\e=0x1B!"
forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c <nul set /p 0x22=!arg1!0x22"
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is just what I needed to clean up my script's output.